# Chromium executable doesn't exist for running Playwright within a deployed Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, chromium, playwright

TL;DR - Does anyone know of a way to run `npx playwright install chromium` after installing Node.js dependencies, and in the Google Cloud Function's production environment?

Is it possible to run Playwright within a deployed Google Cloud Function? I have a deployed function that works fine locally, but when deployed, consistently fails with this error:

```
browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1015/chrome-linux/chrome
```

Fun fact, before using Playwright, I successfully used Puppeteer to successfully deploy the Google Cloud Function. Puppeteer also uses Chromium and had no problems locating and/or installing the Chromium executable (and I am also using only Chromium with Playwright).

I'm pretty sure that running `npx playwright install chromium` after `npm install` would fix the problem, but I'm not sure how to run that command in the Google Cloud Function's environment. I tried doing the following:

```
// package.json

...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "npx playwright install chromium",
  "postci": "npx playwright install chromium"
}
...
```

But that didn't work since I'm getting the same error (and I'm not sure if either post script was executed). Running `npx playwright install chromium` works locally though.

Has anyone successfully ran Playwright in a deployed Google Cloud Function?

## Update

Doing [this approach](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2321#issuecomment-966476038) works when running remotely, but not locally (via an emulated Google Cloud Function). Another problem with that approach is that we're fixed on specific versions of `playwright-core` and `chrome-aws-lambda`.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: I am trying to make Webkit browser work with Playwright and got the same `Executable doesn't exist` error. What I found during debugging is that there was a version mismatch. browserType.launch was looking for ...\ms-playwright\webkit-1683\Playwright.exe executable while the installed version was located in ...\ms-playwright\webkit-1630.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Are you using `executablePath` to point to the installed version? https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch

Comment: This might be a bit unrelated but I wonder why you move from puppeteer to playwright. I'm also curious about the performance between these two. I only need chromium for my use case (no other browsers).

Comment: The reason is, for my use case at the time, I found the APIs to be improved. My playwright script was downloading CSV files, and playwright's `download` event made that much easier than the manual polling method I was using with puppeteer. My script went from 120 lines to 60 for the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't ideal since this is happening at function execution time, but I got this working by calling [spawnSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawnsynccommand-args-options) in the function's body.

```
import { spawnSync } from "child_process";

...
// in the function's body
spawnSync("npx", ["playwright", "install", "chromium"]);
```

This works locally (via [emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite)) and in production.

Comment: Does it mean it will try to install playwwright on every function call?

Comment: Running `npx playwright install chromium` will attempt install chromium every time it is executed.